# Routing a resource to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How do you route a resource to its controller? I am using the resource in an edit page for a different model, so my actions are being routed to its model controller first.

This edit page requests from

```
class Grandstreamers::ResellersController < ApplicationController
def new
end etc...
```

**I am trying to route the requests to** here instead:

```
Grandstreamers::CertificatesController < ApplicationController
def new
end
def update
end etc...
```

This is my form under views/grandstreamers/resellers/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @untrained, :url => certificates_update_path(@untrained) do |f| %>
            <p> Trained Users </p>
            <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@current_trained.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
            <%= f.submit "Un-Train", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>

        <%= form_for @trained, :url => certificates_create_path(@trained) do |f| %>
            <p> Non-Trained Users </p>
            <%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@non_trained.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
            <%= f.submit "Train", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

My route is:

```
resources :certificates
```

Note that the

```
:url => certificates_create_path
```

is not correct and not working. Is there a way to specify this route in my routes.rb file or in my form? Thank you

**EDIT**

This is my resellers_controller edit() which is routes to first.

```
@trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])

  #Trying to get to certificates_controller update. Then update the :attend to "No"
  #@untrained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
  #@untrained = Certificate.find(params[:id])
  #@untrained = Certificate.find_by_user_id(params[:id])
```

@untrained is not defined, I am not sure how to get it to just go to my certificate controller. For @trained I can define it since its not made yet and does not give me errors when it cant find a correct value.

My certificates controller which uses create() but cannot get to update()

```
def create

@trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
if @trained.save
  @trained.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
end
redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path

end

def update
@untrained = Certificate.find(params[:id])
@untrained.update_attributes(attend: "No")
redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
end
```

**Major Issue**
The instance variable @trained and @untrained need to be defined somehow in reseller_controller. What can I define them as to load the edit page?

**Part Solution**

I defined this is in my resellers_controller and it loads the edit page now.

```
@untrained = User.find(params[:id])
```

Now I get this error:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/certificates.1"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I bolded what I am trying to do.

Comment: run "rake routes" to see your routes.. notice that your update path for certificates is certificate(_path) (PUT) and not certificates_update(_path)

Comment: @ilanberci My path for certificates is /certificates/:id(.:format) for #update. The problem is that it needs the instance veriable untrained defined in the resellers_controller since it is being used as a resource under resellers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is you need to let routing know the full name to the controller.

From the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

```
scope module: 'Grandstreamers' do
  resources :certificates
end
```

Use these paths when creating the form:

```
<%= form_for @untrained, :url => certificate_path(@untrained), :method => :put do |f| %>

<%= form_for @trained, :url => certificates_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
```

Comment: There is a typo in certificate, should it be certificates_path(@untrained) ? This still wants @untrained defined in resellers_controller

Answer (score 0):

use this his routes.rb file

```
namespace :grandstreamers do
 resources :certificates
end
```

Comment: This does not define anything different than what is already being routed. The actions are already working for grandstreamers. I need them to go to certificates controller instead of resellers controller. Both are already routed for grandstreamers.

Comment: when you use above code in routes.rb file , then check routes through rake routes. There you found new variable for path then assign that respective path varible that all this is the solution of your problem.

Comment: The routes are already being used by grandstreamers since they are global. It is finding the correct controller already. Jerry Clinesmith was correct with the url: defining.